# summarize comments from a survey using knitr in R

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I made a form using Google Forms to collect a numerical rating of job satisfaction along with indivdiual comments.

I would like to generate an automated Word document report using knitr and rmarkdown to summarize the numerical variables by individual and also include the comments from the text variable in the report.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to include the text comments using knitr and rmarkdown?

Thank you

Comment: Why Word instead of a pdf?

Comment: Just so I could make further edits if needed.  But this isn't necessary if it makes a difference to solve my issue.  I'm happy to get it edited first as needed and then generate a PDF.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to go markdown -> docx via pandoc.  Or is your question more specific?  Do you want to know how to summarize free-form text input?

Comment: Suggested learning: vi, LaTeX, R, sed, awk, python, perl.  If set up correctly, a very repeatable process can be developed to do exactly what you want.  Since you haven't given examples of your input and expected output, it will be difficult to help further.

Comment: yes, I want to be able to summarize free-form text input

Comment: By "summarize free-form text" do you mean something like topic modeling or clustering?